# Bootstrap required attribute in asp.net mvc razor view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I need to use the required attribute, so the field shoud not be empty

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" required>
```

in the razor view, more specifically in this example

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.exclure.libelle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: You could make `libelle` required in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify in `htmlAttributes` with `TextBoxFor()` this way:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.exclure.libelle,new{ @class = "form-control",required="required" })
```